# Is BigQuery reliable for getting PyPI package downloads?

Tags: google-bigquery, pypi

I started a PyPI project a couple weeks ago called [Eebuilder](https://pypi.org/project/Eebuilder/) and google big query says I got 400 downloads on the day I got it working, and 300 when it wasn't working, and only 31 downloads with pip! That brings it up to a unrealistic 700 downloads. Which seems odd because I haven't really shared it any where and gotten any attention.

Comment: Are there bot downloads??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyPI has a number of mirrors which sync with it. The download counts are accurate, but they include these mirrors as well as actual downloads with `pip`. In addition, installs from continuous integration systems are indistinguishable from installs from users typing `pip install ...`.

See ["Analyzing PyPI package downloads"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/?highlight=Downloads) for more details.

Comment: And for substantial data querying savings, use the clustered tables https://towardsdatascience.com/python-pypi-stats-in-bigquery-reclustered-d80e583e1bfe